# c# code to get the installed version of ms-office on server

Tags: asp.net, components, ms-office

I have developed a website where when the user uploads a `.doc` or `.docx` file it will be converted to HTML and stored back to my root directory. The problem I am facing is my server in which my application is hosted does not support Office 2007 and they have Office 2003 components installed on the server.

Is it possible *without* using the Microsoft.Interop.Word.dll to directly read the `.doc` file, convert it to HTML and store in the root directory?

Comment: So are you asking if you can store a binary file in a SQL database?

Comment: no, as it will take lot of space on sqlserver. my question is without using the microsoft.interop.word.dll can we directly read the .doc file and convert it to html and store in the root directory.if so please provide me with any example link

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it.

Take a look on [CreateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524786%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

---

***Edited to add in reply to a comment***

The point with `CreateObject` is that it will use the Word installed in the server, whatever the version installed. The only point is that you have to limit yourself to the lowest version available.

Comment: i dont want to use any com components

Answer (score 0):

A file with the DOCX file extension is a Word Microsoft Office Open XML Format Document file.

The DOC format varies among Microsoft Office Word Formats. Word versions up to 97 used a different format from Microsoft Word version between 97 and 2003.

In Microsoft Office Word 2007 the binary file format was replaced as the default format by the Office Open XML format.

CreateObject can only use the version of the Word engine that is currently installed on the machine, so it may not be able to read the newer versions such as DOCX.